# Can I embed my RCP's ViewPart in a Swing Application?

Tags: swing, swt, rcp, handle

I have an RCP application with a hidden workbench window. I need to reuse the RCP's dialogs and views from a Swing application. The two processes communicate with each other via HTTP.

To display the RCP's SWT dialogs from the Swing Application, on Windows, I pass the window handle of the Swing application's main window to my RCP. It creates a Shell using Shell.win32_new() and uses that to parent the dialog.

Now, I have a ViewPart that I am hoping I can embed in the Swing application. I have tried embedding an SWT widget in my Swing application as described at https://www.eclipsezone.com//eclipse/forums/t60541.html and it works. The problem is in my case, first, its a ViewPart, and second, I need to achieve the embedding across processes. Is this even possible? Is there an approach similar to the window handles that I can employ?

Comment: If the ViewPart depends on other Eclipse plugins then this isn't going to work because the Eclipse plugin system won't have been initialized properly.

Comment: I am running the Workbench, just that the workbench window is hidden. The Workbench will continue to run as long as the Swing application does.

Comment: These are separate processes and JVMs, this simply won't work. Java in one JVM has no access at all to code in another JVM.